# why does push function error out on array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

[image]I am trying to use the .push method in javascript but it errors out and I do not understand why.

```js
var sc = [];
localStorage.setItem("score_history", JSON.stringify(sc));
localStorage.setItem("perfect_score", 0);

function scoreinlocalstorage(perfect_score, winner_score, winner_name) {
  var score_history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history"));
  if (perfect_score < 10) {
    var entry = JSON.parse('{ "name": ' + '"' + winner_name + '", "score": ' + winner_score + "}");

    if (winner_score == 24) {
      var new_score = ParseInt(perfect_score);
      new_score += 1;
      localStorage.setItem("perfect_score", new_score);
    }

    score_history.push(entry);
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I have found the error. It has something to do with the way the if statement if handled.

```
enter code here
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
if(localStorage.getItem("perfect_score") == null ||  
localStorage.getItem("score_history") == null){
    var sc = [];
    localStorage.setItem("score_history",JSON.stringify(sc));
    localStorage.setItem("perfect_score",0);
}....
enter code here
var s=[];
   localStorage.setItem("score_history",JSON.stringify(s));

    var score_history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history"));
    var perfect_score = localStorage.getItem("perfect_score");

    if(perfect_score < 10){


        var entry = JSON.parse('{ "name": '+'"'+winner_name+'", "score": '+winner_score+"}");


        if(winner_score == 24){
            var new_score = parseInt(perfect_score);
            new_score += 1;
            localStorage.setItem("perfect_score", new_score);
        }

        score_history.push(entry);
```

Previously, looking at the log, score_history would return a string, but now it simply returns '[]' which IS correct.
So now my question is, why doesn't my program like the way it is handled in the if statement?

Comment: Can you post what error it gives you ? Especially the error message.

Comment: @Nicolas Edited.

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Post a [mre]. I don’t see any reason why it shouldn’t work.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That is what I have been doing. I still don't understand why it is not working

Comment: _“That is what I have been doing”_ — you mean using the debugging tools? So what is the value of `score_history` and what causes it to change to something that isn’t an array? If it’s still an array, what causes `push` to be overridden or removed? What happens if you use `const` instead of `var` for variables that shouldn’t change value or reference?

Comment: And what is `ParseInt`? How are you calling the function?

Comment: Somewhere you are setting `score_history` to be something other than an array. Currently you have shared only the initial setItem here `localStorage.setItem("score_history", JSON.stringify(sc))`. Where are setting that key after `score_history.push(entry)`? This is not a [mcve]

Comment: @adiga Sorry for the late response. I have uploaded the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1tz6qmw/1/

I am setting score_history by doing this: localStorage.setItem("score_history",JSON.stringify("score_history"));

I am specifically looking at: line 41-45 and lines 252-272 in the JSFiddle link

Comment: `JSON.stringify("score_history")` just stringifies a string. You need to get the JSON string of the array. It should be `localStorage.setItem("score_history", JSON.stringify(scorehistory))`

Comment: @adiga Isn't that what I already have (referring to line 279 in the jsfiddle)? Please let me know if this is the line you are not referring to.

Comment: No, you have written `JSON.stringify("score_history")`. It should be `JSON.stringify(scorehistory)` You are stringifying a string called `"score_history"`. You should instead stringify the array `scorehistory`

Comment: @adiga I tried that and I still get the error. I did a console.log and my scorehistory = "score_history", perfect_score = "0" and entry = {name :"name", score: 2}. Is scorehistory the wrong value?

Comment: @overduekey Where does `scorehistory = "score_history"` come from? You’re doing `var scorehistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history"));`, so use `JSON.stringify(scorehistory);`. `"score_history"` is a _string_, you want to push to the _array_ `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history"))`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon scorehistory = "score_history" came from a console.log output for when i declares var scorehistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history")); I am trying to push the value entry to an array which has the correct values. I've linked another fiddle. Am I misunderstanding you? https://jsfiddle.net/a1tz6qmw/1/

Comment: @SebastianSimon  I've figured out my error. I hardcoded in localStorage.setItem("score_history",JSON.stringify(s)); right before the declaration/implementation of scorehistory. For some reason, when I do  if(localStorage.getItem("perfect_score") == null ||  localStorage.getItem("score_history== null) at the very beginning, my program does not like it at all. Not sure why that would happen. Any ideas? JSFiddle is currently down so I will add it to the main section of this question

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your error, the variable `score_history` is not an array. It might be `null` or `undefined`. You could use a `or` (`||`) operator to verify if the variable is null:

`var score_history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history")) || [];`

this code will check whether or not the value of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score_history"))` is null and if so, initialize the variable `score_history` to an empty array.